# Getting an exception while accessing an Access database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I need to insert a row into the Access table. I have been getting

> object reference not set to instance of an object

My code is:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim strconstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Daisy\My Documents\Downloads\MusicSales.mdb"
    Dim objcon As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    objcon = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strconstring)
    Dim objcommand As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Try
        objcon.Open()
        Dim command As String
        command = "insert into Artists(Artist, Company, Sales )" _
             & " values('" & ArtistBox.Text & "', '" _
             & TextBox2.Text & "', " & TextBox3.Text & ")"
        objcommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(command, objcon)
        da.InsertCommand.CommandText = command
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch exceptionobject As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(exceptionobject.Message)
    Finally
        objcon.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? Does the stack trace show the error happening in your code, or inside one of the function calls?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is a bit of a mess, so that may be causing the problem. Use EITHER...

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Daisy\My Documents\Downloads\MusicSales.mdb;
```

...OR...

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Daisy\My Documents\Downloads\MusicSales.mdb;
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction.I rectified the connection string.Still having the same exception